# Params array being replaced by controller and method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to retrieve the post parameters in my RoR app. However when i print:

```
params
```

It responds with

```
{
"action":"new",
"controller":"question"
}
```

Which is simply the controller and action.. How do i reference the post variables from the controller?

In my log, im getting the error: `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

Comment: That looks like the result of an HTTPGet request not a POST request. Show your log file entries so we can get a better idea of what is happening. A shot in the dark -> It's most likely that you are either using a link instead of a button or you haven't set up your routes for the questions controller

Comment: @jamesw question updated

Comment: That request is not coming from your browser. Looks like you are trying to post from an external source such as a curl command or some other external app. Mobile Phone maybe? Please post the FULL content of your log file entries for that request. We are working totally blind without that

Comment: @jamesw yes im running the app on my local server (webrick), and im using an http tool to create post requests to it. `Started POST "/new/question" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Apr 13 10:16:54 -0400 2013
Processing by QuestionController#new as */*
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

Comment: There's your problem! `Started POST "/new/question"` you have that the wrong way round Rails is looking for a new controller with an action of question which is as I stated as far as rails is concerned, the wrong route. You need to change your post request to questions/new

Comment: @jamesw Really? Even though in my router I have..   `match "/new/question" => "question#new", :via => :post`

Comment: Also, the new action is successfully being reached...

Comment: Ahh, yes, you are correct. Sorry. What params are you sending? There don;t seem to be any in that log entry. And how are you sending them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28166/discussion-between-jonah-katz-and-jamesw)

Answer (score 1):

That is how you get post variables. If they're not there then there's a problem with your form or whatever is making the request.

Comment: hmm. So why is it printing action controller? Is it supposed to have those in addition to the post parameters?

Comment: Simple answer... Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

Ditch your custom route `match "/new/question" => "question#new", :via => :post` You don't need it and it's just confusing matters. new actions don't accept params and should ONLY respond to GET requests.

Just send an HTTPPOST request to `your/url/questions` and rails will know to call the create action and you can pass in whatever params you need.

The new action is for rendering a form not for accepting POST requests.
Likewise if you send a PUT request to `your/url/questions` rails just knows to call the update action in the questions controller. That's the whole point of RESTfull routes.

Answer (score -1):

Dude, are you including the "csrf_meta_tags" in your layout?

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

If not, then rails will ditch all POST parameters...

Comment: There is no layout. Read the comments under the question